# How to insert polygon into database with PostGIS extension

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgis, psql

I have a table with fields created in such way:

```
CREATE TABLE buildings(id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY, geom GEOMETRY, name VARCHAR(30));
```

and I want to insert simple 2D building into it with following coordinates
8 4,
10.5 4,
10.5 1.5,
8 1.5

```
INSERT INTO buildings(id, geom, name)
VALUES
(1, ST_GeomFromText('POLYGON(8 4, 10.5 4, 10.5 1.5, 8 1.5)'), 'BuildingA');
```

for some reason I get an error

```
ERROR:  parse error - invalid geometry
HINT:  "POLYGON(8 4" <-- parse error at position 11 within geometry
```

How can I insert that polygon into the table?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`ST_GeomFromText` takes a WKT as its argument. If you look at [the WKT format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-known_text), you'll see that you need another pair of brackets for your polygon. You'll also want the last point in the polygon to match the first one.

```sql
INSERT INTO buildings(id, geom, name)
VALUES
(1, ST_GeomFromText('POLYGON((8 4, 10.5 4, 10.5 1.5, 8 1.5, 8 4))'), 'BuildingA');
```